# can you set a predetermined billing app qt?

Tags: qml

can you set a vertical orientation in a qml app?
if so?

I have searched on various sites to try and solve this problem. I found it in C ++ code but I would need the piece of code in qml language

I'm using the application project - qt quick application - empty
I'm using a version of qt 5.10.1

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `Screen.orientationUpdateMask`.
Once the mask is set, `Screen.orientation` will contain the current orientation of the screen.You can read more about the Screem QML type [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-screen.html). Of course the orientation in this case is set by the accelerometer.

If you want to be able to go back and forth between portrait and landscape without the use of the accelerometer and while having the logic in qml you will need to use the `Transform`, `Scale` and `Rotation` QML types. I wouldn't recommend this approach.

One alternative to using `Transform` would be to use two different views all together, which might not be a good idea for maintainability especially if you want to use the 4 orientations.

If you want to force the orientation no matter what you can do it in the manifest file as you would normally without Qt.